# My bot works with Skype, can I use Skype for Business?

Tags: botframework, skype-for-business

I've been able to make a bot run in Azure and connect to it using web chat and skype. Am I able to communicate with the Bot using Skype for Business? If so, how can I add it as a contact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Skype for Business is not supported at all as of this moment. I can imagine support might come in the future but nothing has been announced yet.

Comment: It's now almost an year. Any update on this ? Are they even planning to roll out this for Skype for Business ?

Answer (score 1):

Does not look like the botframework works with skype for business just yet..

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/138